# Communicating with ViewPager and Dialogs in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-button, android-dialogfragment

So I've been reading about Dialogs in Android and am curious on how to implement this to my current code.

I followed the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) to create a custom layout. I created it as a new class.

```
public class AddSiteDialog extends DialogFragment {

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null))

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    AddSiteDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

}
```

Now I want that dialog to show when I click a button inside of a ViewPager layout. In a different class. `public class FieldsActivity extends Activity {`

where I have the ViewPager.

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    final ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fieldspager);

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        final ArrayList<String> siteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_row, siteList);

        if(lv == null) Log.v("lv", "null");
        else Log.v("aa", "null");

        if (lv != null) {
            lv.setAdapter(aa);
        }
        int resId = 0;
        View view = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.field01;
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

                return view;

            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.add_site;
                view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                Button addSiteButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addSiteButton);
                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
                addSiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     //I want to click this button and the dialog show up
                    }
                });
                return view;
```

How would i implement this there.

I'm pretty new at this, so I'm trying to figure out how things talk to each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to subclass FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter.

In the 'getItem(...)' your Fragment(State)PagerAdapter, you return a Fragment that contains the 'addSiteButton' button you mention.

Your Fragment declares a Callback interface:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment { 
  ...
  ...
  public interface Callback {
      public void showDialog();
  }

  private Callback mCallback;


  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    callback = (Callback)activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    callback = null;
    super.onDetach();
  }

  ....
  ....
      // Onclick handler of 'addSiteButton'.
      onClick(View view) {
        if (callback != null) {
          callback.showDialog();
        }
      }
  ....
}
```

And make sure that your Activity implements Callback:

```
public class FieldsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MyFragment.Callback {

  ....
  ....
  @Override
  public void showDialog() {
    // Put the code you already have to create the dialogFragment.
  }
}
```